# What is this Jini technology?

Tags: java, apache, jini

This question is about the Jini technology. In Head First Java book, the authors say they expect their readers to get experienced in Jini, when the time is correct. However, few months ago, I found out this Jini is now Apache River. I really wanted to learn it because I have heard it is capable of doing cool stuff like controlling your TV,  your fan, oven etc from your computer. Now, following are my questions

1. From where can I learn this technology from the beginning? (Please don't give the following link http://river.apache.org/user-guide-basic-river-services.html because it has no help for a beginner with this technology)
2. Do I need electronic engineering knowledge to work with it? (If yes, either I have to give up or find a guy with that knowledge)
3. Do I need cost full devices to work with it? (Lile antennas, remote controllers)
4. Why there are no books about it? (I have seen 2 Java Robotic books after a huge search. Unfortunately they are older than 10 years)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there is an element of confusion here. There is no direct connection between Jini and robotics or controlling your TV than any other java technology, jini is a distributed object service which lets services communicate and find other services. 
You could use it to control things if you wanted to, if your services provided those details, and maybe there is the confusion because i think lego mindstorms does, but it is no more dedicated to robotics than anything else is.

Probably worth reading the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jini) description for it

Comment: My goodness, then am I following the wrong technology? I need to learn the technology which can do stuff I mentioned. If it is not Jini, what's it?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do? Most of the things you speak of need extra hardware so you need to decide what specifically it is you want.

Comment: Actually, I need to control few of my items like, fan, tv, etc using Java. At least, what is the name of the technology which can do these?

Comment: There is no specific technology, many technologies could do it. These things are easy enough to control if you have the hardware for it. To control your tv you need some kind of IR interface. To control your fan you need a power interface. Find the interfaces first, then look for the technology.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for the info Woody.  I really appreciate it :)